# typeGraphql how to change message for Field validation

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

I am using an InputType with Fields:

```
@InputType('RegisterInput')
export default class RegisterInput {
    @Field({nullable: true})
    username: string
    @Field({nullable: true})
    password: string
    @Field({nullable: true})
    age?: number
}
```

And when age is not a number I get an error like:

```
UserInputError {
  message: 'Variable "$registerInput" got invalid value "text" at "registerInput.age"; Int cannot represent non-integer value: "text"',
  locations: [ { line: 1, column: 19 } ],
  path: undefined,
  extensions: { code: 'BAD_USER_INPUT' }
}
```

How can I change the message to be more user friendly? All kind of middleware and class validations I tried still first produce this error and then any other error.

It is even better if I can dissable it and do the validation in my middleware.

I tried using graphql-middleware, but still the middleware is called only after this validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change that easily because it's the standard GraphQL query validation from `graphql-js`. It analyse your query statically and sees when you do not provide some input or providing variable of wrong type.

It happens before the whole graphql execution pipeline, with middlewares and others comes into play.